# How to disable clicks on DotView?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-viewpager2

I am using a custom view from [here](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator). I want to disable user interactions with the view pager 2 using this:

```java
binding.viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

But, it moves when I click on a dot of that view. I tried to disable that using this:

```java
binding.dotsView.setEnabled(false);
```

But, that does not seem to work.

Then how can we disable clicks on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library uses setOnClickListener internally to enables the click listener. Use below line.

`binding.dotsView.setOnClickListener(null)`

So, a null click listener can be set to disable future clicks. After setting the view to a null click listener.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I had to give many properties and then it got disabled:

```java
binding.dots.setDotsClickable(false);
binding.dots.setOnClickListener(null);
binding.dots.setEnabled(false);
binding.dots.setClickable(false);
```